# Using command line arguments in imported module

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse, peewee

I have script `download.py` with:

```
import argparse
import models

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--db_path", required=True)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

`models.py`:

```
import peewee

database = peewee.SqliteDatabase("wee.db")

class Artist(peewee.Model):
    name = peewee.CharField()

    class Meta:
        database = database

class Album(peewee.Model):
    artist = peewee.ForeignKeyField(Artist)
    title = peewee.CharField()
    release_date = peewee.DateTimeField()
    publisher = peewee.CharField()
    media_type = peewee.CharField()

    class Meta:
        database = database
```

Instead of `wee.db` I'd like to use database path from `args.db_path` in `download.py` file. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is pass your arg to the `SqliteDatabase` constructor.

It seems like you're using Django. If that's the case, you could (and should) specify your database in `settings.py`, [as indicated on the docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASES)

EDIT

Here is a code example of how to do it with your existing code the way you suggested (I still think there are betters way of doing this):

`models.py`:

```
database_name = "wee_db"

def set_database_name(name):
    database_name = name

database = peewee.SqliteDatabase(database_name)
```

`download.py`:

```
models.set_database_name(args.db_path)
```

Comment: No, I'm not using Django, and when I pass `args.db_path` I get: `NameError: name 'args' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

```
# download.py
import argparse
from models import DBManager

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--db_path", required=True)

args = parser.parse_args()
DBManager(args.db_path)
```

---

```
# models.py
import peewee


class Artist(peewee.Model):
    name = peewee.CharField()


class Album(peewee.Model):
    artist = peewee.ForeignKeyField(Artist)
    title = peewee.CharField()
    release_date = peewee.DateTimeField()
    publisher = peewee.CharField()
    media_type = peewee.CharField()


class DBManager(object):

    def __init__(self, db_path):
        self.database = peewee.SqliteDatabase(db_path)

        Artist._meta.database = self.database
        Album._meta.database = self.database

        self.database.connect()
        self.database.create_tables([Artist, Album])
```